# ffmpeg live stream show image

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

Is there a way in ffmpeg to show a looped video or image if an incoming udp:// stream is not active?

Pretty much like having a player show a wait for braodcast to start image/video until the live stream begins.

Comment: Pardon the confusion, but are you looking for a method to display a "please stand by" (PSB) image locally while waiting for an external 3rd party stream to start, or are you looking for a way to push a PSB in front of a live stream you're producing yourself?

Comment: looking for a "please stand by" image while waiting for a 3rd party stream to start

Comment: OK. And are you looking to record this stream or just play it back? If recording, did you want to include the PSB image or not?

Comment: i'm looking to publish it to like nginx-rtmp via rtmp then nginx-rtmp will handle the different streaming formats like hls/rtmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the trick... FFmpeg and its related tools, FFserver and FFplay, don't have any mechanism for live input-switching to a single running output. They also don't have any built-in way to trigger an external event when a UDP stream starts up; at least none that I've been able to find.

In order to pull off your intended action, *one* solution would be to start up an instance of FFmpeg to push a stream of your PSB image up to your server, then -- once the genuine UDP stream starts coming through -- kill that stream and start up a 2nd one with the UDP stream's contents. Both FFmpeg and FFplay will 'spin' (i.e., sit in a listening state) if a UDP stream input is specified but the stream isn't being received, so a logged instance of FFplay can be used as trigger. (Starting a 2nd instance of FFmpeg while the first one is running is just going to muck up the stream transmission to your server).

Of course, killing the first stream and starting a 2nd may not be ideal, but if a very short interruption in the RTMP stream is acceptable, it should do the trick for you. If no interruption is acceptable, you'd have to go the route of pushing both the PSB image and UDP streams to named pipes, then pushing them out to your RTMP server through a 3rd instance of FFmpeg using the concat demuxer. In that case, you'd need exactly-matching video and audio encoders in both initial streams for the concat to work, and since you're pulling in a 3rd party stream, there's a potential for problems if the original streamer changes their settings.

Anyway, here's a link to a pretty basic bash script that runs the kill1-start2 scenario as I've described.[(Script on Slexy.org)](http://slexy.org/view/s20scHKLld). I'll warn you that I'm no scripting expert, so someone might come up with a simpler and/or cleaner method of doing this.